# Pie chart with custom layout

Tags: html, css, d3.js

Is it possible to implement a custom layout for a pie chart in D3 such as below?

The blue things has position with out of circle boundary.
Many example shows how to pie chart, but this layout has little wieard shape.
I wondering whether it is possible or not.

[image: sample pie]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is.  All you have to do is offset the parts after drawing them using d3's pie chart functionality @see https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Pie-Layout